# stat_density2d Contour Plot Legend and Points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following contour plot (I am not able to reproduce the exact same data, so I placed the figure below).

[image: Contour Plot]

The code used:

```
contPlot <- (ggplot(data=gg, aes(x=wf, y=wb, z=z)) + geom_point(aes(colour=z)) 
 + stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..),n = 100,contour = TRUE,geom = "polygon"))
contPlot + labs(x=expression(w[f]),y=expression(w[b]))
```

Now I would like to:
-Remove the level legend level, associated with the estimated density.
-Remove the points below the estimated density, but keeping the 'z' legend.
-Rename the 'z' legend.

How can do the above? I am beginner with ggplot2, so please bear with me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

- Faked some data
- Then used the `shape=""` to prevent the points from being shown.
- Turned off the fill guide, supressing the guide titled "level"
- I should have been able to change the title of the color legend with `guide_legend` with the `title` parameter but that messed up the guide (maybe a `gplot2 2.0.0` bug?)
- So renamed the `z` variable to the title I wanted (`My Title`) and enclosed it in backticks so as to give me freedom to choose any title.

Yielding this:

```
# fake data
set.seed(1234)
n <- 200
gg <- data.frame(wf=rnorm(n,0.5),wb=rnorm(n,0.5),z=runif(n,0,6))

# plot it
gg$`My Title` <- gg$z
ggplot(data=gg, aes(x=wf, y=wb, color=`My Title`)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=z),shape="") +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..),n = 100,contour = TRUE,geom = "polygon") +
  labs(x=expression(w[f]),y=expression(w[b])) +
  guides(fill=F)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That worked fine! One last question: I would like to put greek letters in the legend, is it possible?